# NumPy array row wise and column wise slicing syntax

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why does NumPy allow `array[row_index, ]` but `array[, col_index]` is not valid and gives Syntax Error. e.g. if I want to traverse the array row wise `NumPy.array[row_index, :]` and `NumPy.array[row_index, ]` both give the same answer where as only `NumPy.array[:, col_index]` produces the result in the latter case. Is there any reason behind this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

`arr[idx,]` is actually short for `arr[(idx,)]`, passing a tuple to the `__getitem__` method.  In python a comma creates a tuple (in most circumstances).  `(1)` is just `1`, `(1,)` is a one element tuple, as is `1,`.

`arr[,idx]` is gives a syntax error. That's the interpreter complaining, not `numpy`.

`arr[3]`, `arr[3,]` and `arr[3,:]` are all the same for a 2d array.  Trailing `:` are added as needed.  Leading `:` have to be explicit.